# Function call in all templates

Tags: python, django, twitter

I want to have a variable in any template in django. This variable contains all of tweet twittter and I show it in the footer. Here's what you do:
1)I custom_context file which has the following code:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
from codebase import settings

def get_last_tweet(request):
api = TwitterAPI(settings.CONSUMERKEY, settings.CONSUMERSECRET, settings.ACCESSTOKEN,    settings.ACCESSTOKENSECRET)
r = api.request('statuses/user_timeline', {'count': 10})
tweets = [result['text'] for result in r.get_iterator()]
return {'tweets': tweets}
```

Here's what it looks like and TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  'django.core.context_processors.static',
  'django.core.context_processors.media',
  'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
  'django.core.context_processors.tz',
  'django.core.context_processors.debug',
  'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
  'home.custom_context.get_last_tweet',
)
```

and when I run a template appears to me the following error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with Django templates or context processors. Does `get_last_tweet` method works on its own?

Answer (score 0):

It is about your api call.

r = api.request('statuses/user_timeline', {'count': 10}) gives request timeout i think.

why dont u try to debug the cunction call?